# Can somebody explain what the Z value is in 3D shapes?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

In Computer Graphics, we have to draw 3D shapes and there are the x, y and z values.

For example, this vertices will draw a cube along with some other stuff. 
But what I'm confused about is the z value.
Can somebody explain to me what the z value does?
And what is the difference in -z and +z values?

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
-0.2, -0.2, -0.2, 1.0, // 0
-0.2, -0.2, +0.2, 1.0, // 1
-0.2, +0.2, -0.2, 1.0, // 2
-0.2, +0.2, +0.2, 1.0, // 3
+0.2, -0.2, -0.2, 1.0, // 4
+0.2, -0.2, +0.2, 1.0, // 5
+0.2, +0.2, -0.2, 1.0, // 6
+0.2, +0.2, +0.2, 1.0, // 7
};
```

Comment: A 3 dimensional object in a 3 dimensional space has 3 coordinates. I recommend to read a tutorial, for instance about [Camera and View space](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera)

Comment: Three dimensions, x, y, and z? Seems fairly obvious to me. If it was only x and y it would be two dimensional.

Comment: i suppose you are asking for the 4th coordinate, not `z` ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you :)

Comment: To achieve [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) are used.

Comment: @john Yes I know x and y is 2D. And I know x, y and z is 3D. I'm just asking for explanation of the z value

Comment: @idclev463035818 Nope, I'm asking about the 3rd coordinate, the z value

Comment: @JustTryingToGraduate The z value is a coordinate just like x and y. When the object is projected the on the 2 dimensional viewport then, the view space z coordinate defines the depth. The depth is required for the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test). At perspective projection the size of the object depends on the viewspace z distance to the point of view.

Comment: then I am as puzzled as the others. A point in 3D needs 3 coordinates, x,y, and z...

Comment: In OpenGL, the z value can be used in the vertex shader (like if you have a projection matrix, and you multiply it). In terms of the output of the vertex shader, the resulting Z value does not affect the location of the vertex besides clipping out of bound vertices (outside of -1 ... 1), but it does affect textures. Also, if you are using z-buffering, it will affect that as well.

Comment: In 3D graphics, the Z ordinate can be thought of as depth, such as going to the background or coming into the foreground.